# Writing Background color

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying write background color got from three SeekBars.
I use this code :

```
SharedPreferences mColor;
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_COLOR="color";
    colorS = rgbToHEX(r, g, b);
    try {

                Editor editor = mColor.edit();
                editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_COLOR, colorS);
                editor.apply();
                } catch(Exception e){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }
```

But I see message "java.lang.NullPointerExeption"
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences is null when you get the Editor. Try:

```
mColor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor editor = mColor.edit();
editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_COLOR, colorS);
editor.commit();
```

that should fix your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. Or I can't understand what I should white instead "appContext_or_activity context"?